# Django error during template rendering because URL tag

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, url, model-view-controller

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

    Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(3,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$(?P<college_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

The error is on this line:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'app:detail' college.id %}">{{ college.college_name }}</a></li>
```

Here is the whole template (index.html):

```
{% if latest_college_list %}

<ul>
    {% for college in latest_college_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'app:detail' college.id %}">{{ college.college_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
<p> No colleges available </p>
{% endif %}
```

The view:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import College

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    latest_college_list = College.objects.order_by('college_name')
    context = {'latest_college_list': latest_college_list}
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)

def detail(request, college_id):
    college = get_object_or_404(College, pk=college_id)
    return render(request, 'app/detail.html', {'college':college})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "app"
urlpatterns = [
    # campusarchitecture.com/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    # /college_name
    url(r'^(?P<college_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name="detail")
]
```

root urls conf:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('app.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What is the error you get? Also, what does your root url conf look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
url(r'^$', include('app.urls')),
```

Should be

```
url(r'^', include('app.urls', namespace="app")),
```

Note the `$` should be removed as it indicates the end of the regex pattern, and it would not discover the included url patterns.

Secondly, you need to explicitly specify the `namespace` in the `include`. More on this in the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).

Similarly, remove the `$` after the `login/` URL pattern match too.

Comment: Thank you so much!